# Driverless printing with CUPS: client-error-bad-request / "Print job was not accepted."

Tags: debian, printing, cups, debian-bookworm

I’ve just installed Debian Bookworm (12) on my workstation and can’t print via network on my **Kyocera M2040dn** anymore. It worked on Debian Bullseye (11) but I can’t recall if I needed to install the PPD back then. (I have a whole disk image backup of the old system but don’t how to extract this info from the old filesystem.)

[image]

- http://localhost:631/jobs/ shows *Print job was not accepted.* for any print job (The number of *Pages* seems to increase for every trial of printing)
- the log `/var/log/cups/error_log` completes jobs with `client-error-bad-request`

I regularly use different IPP network printers in different offices and really want to get **driverless printing** to work. CUPS detects the printer just fine and seems to send my print job to the device.

1. I don’t really understand the error message. What is exactly is wrong? Which step failed?
2. What could fix this?

Here’s what I have and what I’ve done:

- both printer and workstation are connected via LAN on the same subnet
- I can ping both the printer’s IP address 192.168.1.219 (which it got via DHCP) and it’s alias M2040dn.local
- I tried to powercycle the printer according to https://superuser.com/a/1563718/56756
- I am not aware of any restrictions I had enabled on the printer. Anyone on the same subnet can print just fine. It worked before and I definitely didn’t change the printer config since then.
- As far as I understand the log CUPS can establish a TCP connection and they successfully exchange device information about the printer and print data of my document
- I have enabled debug logging with

```
$ sudo cupsctl --debug-logging
$ sudo cupsctl LogLevel=debug2
```

- additionally to the autodiscovered printer I tried to manually add a printer with explicit hostname following https://askubuntu.com/a/1422434/465184 with the following command but it turns to the same error *Print job was not accepted.* in http://localhost:631/jobs/

```
$ sudo lpadmin -p Kyocera_ECOSYS_M2040dn -v "ipps://Kyocera%20ECOSYS%20M2040dn._ipps._tcp.local/" -E -m everywhere
```

Here’s an example job log. The last part repeats over and over again while CUPS tried to complete the job.

```
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Applying default options...
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Adding default copies=1
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Adding default cups-browsed-dest-printer=\"8 ipps://Kyocera%20ECOSYS%20M2040dn._ipps._tcp.local/ pdf 600dpi\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Adding default finishings=0
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Adding default job-cancel-after=10800
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Adding default job-hold-until=no-hold
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Adding default media=iso_a4_210x297mm
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Adding default notify-events=job-completed
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Adding default notify-lease-duration=86400
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Adding default number-up=1
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Adding default orientation-requested=0
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Adding default output-bin=top
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Adding default print-quality=0
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Adding default printer-resolution=600x600dpi
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Adding default sides=two-sided-long-edge
I [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Adding start banner page "none".
I [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Adding end banner page "none".
I [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] File of type application/pdf queued by "daniel".
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] hold_until=0
I [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Queued on "Kyocera_ECOSYS_M2040dn" by "daniel".
d [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] cupsdCheckJobs: Job 10 - dest="Kyocera_ECOSYS_M2040dn", printer=(nil), state=3, cancel_time=0, hold_until=0, kill_time=0, pending_cost=0, pending_timeout=0
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] time-at-processing=1708601381
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] 3 filters for job:
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] pdftopdf (application/pdf to application/vnd.cups-pdf, cost 66)
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] - (application/vnd.cups-pdf to printer/Kyocera_ECOSYS_M2040dn/application/pdf, cost 10)
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] - (printer/Kyocera_ECOSYS_M2040dn/application/pdf to printer/Kyocera_ECOSYS_M2040dn, cost 0)
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] job-sheets=none,none
d [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Mapping output-bin to OutputBin=Top
d [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] After mapping finishings OutputBin=Top
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] argv[0]="Kyocera_ECOSYS_M2040dn"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] argv[1]="10"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] argv[2]="daniel"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] argv[3]="MyPDF.pdf"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] argv[4]="1"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] argv[5]="PageSize=A4 EPRendering=None XRXColor=BW INK=MONO SelectColor=Grayscale HPColorMode=GrayscalePrint ProcessColorModel=Mono BRMonoColor=Mono CNGrayscale PrintoutMode=Normal.Gray BRPrintQuality=Black Collate Duplex=DuplexNoTumble ColorMode=Mono CNIJGrayScale=1 ARCMode=CMBW ColorModel=Gray OKControl=Gray XROutputColor=PrintAsGrayscale BLW=TrueM job-uuid=urn:uuid:436a9578-62ae-3e55-55fe-2ba2e49b136a cups-browsed-dest-printer=\\\"8\\ ipps://Kyocera%20ECOSYS%20M2040dn._ipps._tcp.local/\\ pdf\\ 600dpi\\\" finishings=0 media=iso_a4_210x297mm number-up=1 orientation-requested=0 output-bin=top print-quality=0 printer-resolution=600x600dpi sides=two-sided-long-edge job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1708601381 time-at-processing=1708601381 OutputBin=Top"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00010-001"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[3]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[4]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[6]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[7]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[8]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[9]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@my-workstation"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[10]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.4.2"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[11]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[12]="USER=root"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[13]="CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[14]="CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[15]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[16]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[17]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[18]="LANG=en_US.UTF-8"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[19]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/Kyocera_ECOSYS_M2040dn.ppd"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[20]="CONTENT_TYPE=application/pdf"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[21]="DEVICE_URI=ipps://M2040dn.local:443/ipp/print"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[22]="PRINTER_INFO=Kyocera_ECOSYS_M2040dn"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[23]="PRINTER_LOCATION="
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[24]="PRINTER=Kyocera_ECOSYS_M2040dn"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[25]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=media-empty-report"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[26]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[27]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/pdf"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] envp[28]="AUTH_I****"
I [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 768747)
I [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/ipps (PID 768748)
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Sending stdin for job...
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Looking up \"M2040dn.local\"...
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] pdftopdf: Last filter determined by the PPD: -; FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE: application/pdf => pdftopdf will log pages in page_log.
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] M2040dn.local=192.168.1.219
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] backendWaitLoop(snmp_fd=5, addr=0x5566b3764b68, side_cb=0x5566b35cb070)
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] PDF interactive form and annotation flattening done via QPDF
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] pdftopdf: \"print-scaling\" IPP attribute: auto
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] pdftopdf: Print scaling mode: Do not scale, center, crop if needed
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] After Cropping: 596.000000 842.000000 595.275574 841.889771
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] After Cropping: 596.000000 842.000000 595.275574 841.889771
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] PAGE: 1 1
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] PAGE: 2 1
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Connecting to M2040dn.local:443
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] PID 768747 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Connecting to printer.
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:41 +0100] [Job 10] Set job-printer-state-message to "Connecting to printer.", current level=INFO
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] update_reasons(attr=0(), s=\"-cups-certificate-error\")
d [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] op=\'-\', new_reasons=1, state_reasons=1
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] Connection is encrypted.
d [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] cupsdCheckJobs: Job 10 - dest="Kyocera_ECOSYS_M2040dn", printer=0x55c8fce1ba70, state=5, cancel_time=1708612181, hold_until=0, kill_time=0, pending_cost=0, pending_timeout=0
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] Credentials are OK/trusted ((null))
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] Printer credentials: M2040dn (issued by unknown) / Mon, 05 Jul 2027 01:34:03 GMT / RSA-SHA256 / 46297C9BE8AF66337FFCC8495A017A1D
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] Stored credentials: M2040dn (issued by unknown) / Mon, 05 Jul 2027 01:34:03 GMT / RSA-SHA256 / 46297C9BE8AF66337FFCC8495A017A1D
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] update_reasons(attr=0(), s=\"-cups-pki-invalid,cups-pki-changed,cups-pki-expired,cups-pki-unknown\")
d [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] op=\'-\', new_reasons=4, state_reasons=1
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] update_reasons(attr=0(), s=\"-connecting-to-device\")
d [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] op=\'-\', new_reasons=1, state_reasons=1
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] Connected to printer.
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] Set job-printer-state-message to "Connected to printer.", current level=INFO
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] Connected to 192.168.1.219:443...
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] Getting supported attributes...
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] Get-Printer-Attributes: successful-ok-ignored-or-substituted-attributes (successful-ok-ignored-or-substituted-attributes)
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] copies-supported=1-999
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] document-format-supported (10 values)
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [0] = \"application/octet-stream\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [1] = \"application/pdf\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [2] = \"image/tiff\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [3] = \"image/jpeg\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [4] = \"image/urf\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [5] = \"application/postscript\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [6] = \"application/vnd.hp-PCL\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [7] = \"application/vnd.hp-PCLXL\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [8] = \"application/vnd.xpsdocument\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [9] = \"image/pwg-raster\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] media-col-supported (7 values)
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [0] = \"media-size\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [1] = \"media-bottom-margin\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [2] = \"media-left-margin\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [3] = \"media-right-margin\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [4] = \"media-top-margin\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [5] = \"media-source\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [6] = \"media-type\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] operations-supported (9 values)
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [0] = Print-Job
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [1] = Validate-Job
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [2] = Cancel-Job
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [3] = Send-Document
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [4] = Create-Job
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [5] = Get-Job-Attributes
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [6] = Get-Jobs
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [7] = Get-Printer-Attributes
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] [8] = Identify-Printer
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] Sleeping...  
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] Set job-printer-state-message to "Sleeping...  ", current level=INFO
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] update_reasons(attr=1(media-empty-report), s=\"(null)\")
d [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] op=\' \', new_reasons=1, state_reasons=1
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] ATTR: marker-colors=\'\"#000000\"\',\'\"none\"\'
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] ATTR: marker-high-levels=100,95
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] ATTR: marker-levels=70,0
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] ATTR: marker-low-levels=5,0
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] ATTR: marker-names=\'\"Black TK-1170S\"\',\'\"Waste Toner Box\"\'
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] ATTR: marker-types=\'\"toner\"\',\'\"waste-toner\"\'
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] final_content_type=\"application/pdf\", document_format=\"application/pdf\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] retryable=1
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] Validate-Job IPP/2.0
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] printer-uri=\"ipps://M2040dn.local:443/ipp/print\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] requesting-user-name=\"daniel\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] job-name=\"MyPDF.pdf\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] document-format=\"application/pdf\"
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] Adding standard IPP operation/job attributes.
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] IPP/2.0 Validate-Job #2
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] ---- operation-attributes-tag ----
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] attributes-charset charset utf-8
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] attributes-natural-language naturalLanguage en-us
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] printer-uri uri ipps://M2040dn.local:443/ipp/print
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] requesting-user-name nameWithoutLanguage daniel
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] job-name nameWithoutLanguage MyPDF.pdf
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] document-format mimeMediaType application/pdf
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] ---- job-attributes-tag ----
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] media-col collection {media-size={x-dimension=21000 y-dimension=29700} media-bottom-margin=400 media-left-margin=400 media-right-margin=400 media-top-margin=400}
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] output-bin keyword top
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] print-color-mode keyword auto-monochrome
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] print-quality enum 0
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] sides keyword two-sided-long-edge
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] multiple-document-handling keyword separate-documents-collated-copies
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] ---- end-of-attributes-tag ----
D [22/Feb/2024:12:29:42 +0100] [Job 10] Validate-Job: client-error-bad-request (client-error-bad-request)
...
```

(IP subnet, workstation hostname, original PDF name redacted for privacy)

Comment: I am not certain about this, but I think that the driverless print operating system has embedded functions to print. That is, it is not really truly driverless.  If your operating system does not have the embedded printing capability, you need to install the driver.

Comment: Well, "driverless" is obviously a bit exaggerated but the real promise is that any system capable of IPP driverless printing can “just print” without taking care of *device-specific* drivers. I firmly believe CUPS should be capable to do so. If something generic was missing, e.g. due to incomplete dependency requirements, I’d happily install that to solve the issue.

Comment: You need to install the correct driver.  Your OS does not have what is needed